# Calculus Past Paper Question

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\alpha$ be a positive real number. Without evaluating the integral, show that:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(\alpha x)dx}{x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(x) dx}{x}$$

and so is independent of $\alpha$

Comment: I might add, in case you are wondering why the downvotes, it is most likely due to what appears to be a lack of effort on your behalf. It is a good idea to post your workings in the question, and the likes!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Also, it seems you haven't accepted any answer to your questions yet. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2):

let $u = \alpha x$ so $du = \alpha dx $

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(\alpha x)dx}{x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(u) \frac{du}{\alpha}}{\frac{u}{\alpha}} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{sin(u)du}{u}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\alpha x$ so that $du=\alpha dx$, $x=u/a$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\alpha x)}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u/\alpha}\frac{du}{\alpha}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du.
$$
It remains to recognize that '$u$' in the rightmost expression above is just a label which may be replaced with, say, '$x$'.

Answer (score 1):

Both the posted answers are the answer I would present on an exam. However, you could look at it from a visual perspective.

Firstly, on your favourite graphing calculator (for example, google Desmos graphing calculator) try graph $sin(ax)/x$ for some positive real $a$. You should observe that it has the effect of pulling curves in the graph closer together and raising their peaks as $a$ gets bigger than $1$, and vice versa as $a$ gets smaller than $1$.

To understand how this affects the integral, look at the following graphs of $sin(ax)/x$ (notice there is a discontinuity at $x=0$). The green, red and blue correspond to $a=1,2,3$ respectively. As you can see, the lowest part of the red function's first dip is twice that of the dip of the green function (with rounding error). And similarly for the blue one. This constant stretching of the peaks (and the functions) continues all the way to infinity along with the shortening of the curves, and so gives the same integral regardless of $a$. Notice that the integral is not the same regardless of $a$ if we went from say, $0$ to $2$ since in that case we would not be including the same peaks. For example, blue would have a lower peak, but red would not, in the interval [$0$,$2$]. [image]

Perhaps it would be useful to note that: (Which you can generalise for $a$) $$\int_{0}^{\pi/3} \frac{sin(3x)dx}{x} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{sin(x) dx}{x}$$
Using this, you could actually split up your original integral into an infinite series of smaller integrals to get the answer.

Comment: If you happen to be colour blind, please let me know, and I apologise if so, since the graph is colour coded.